# How to solve PermissionError:[Errno13] using Python matplotlib.pyplot.savefig in Ubuntu 18.04 apache2 server Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, ubuntu

I made a line chart using this code in Django, Python 3.6, Apache2, Ubuntu 18.04
Before moved to the server(Ubuntu), I tested in my local environment(Mac OS), And it worked.

```
def saveChart(request):
    ...
    plt.plot(val1, var2)
    plt.savefig('django project dir/static/chart.png')
    plt.close()
```

And I got PermissionError:[Errno13] with plt.savefig()

I've tried to give a 777 permission on my `view.py` but it didn't work.
Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your conf file

projectname.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com   
    ServerAlias  www.example.com   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foldername/projectname 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/foldername/projectname/projectname.wsgi 
    Alias /static /var/www/foldername/static/static_only 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

you need to mention your document root folder in Apache config file and run below command

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/foldername
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I give the 777 to my static folder. And I faced one prob more. Is it something authority things needed to overwrite image files using savefig()? I cannot overwrite .png file

Comment: Oh Idk why, but it worked anyway. It took some time for some reason to overwrite files. Thanks Mr Kumar!